# Liferay DXP 7.2: Add Permissions/Roles Of Viewing Different Pages To An Organization

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a single site in Liferay DXP 7.2, and I would like to know what is the best way to add permissions/roles of viewing different pages to an organization.

**Requirements:**

- This site will be owned/shared by 2 organizations.
- Each organization has a number of site roles.
- Each site role consists of permissions for viewing different sets of pages. For example, `Role 1` can view `page A` and `page B`, whereas `Role 2` can view `page C` and `page D`.

**Desired Outcome:**

- **Roles:**

  - `Role 1`: view public page only.
  - `Role 2`: view public and admin pages only.
  - `Role 3`: view private page only.
- **Organizations:**

  - `Organization 1` has `Role 1` and `Role 2`, which can be assigned to members within `Organization 1`.
  - `Organization 2` has `Role 1` and `Role 3`, which can be assigned to members within `Organization 2`.

**Encountered Problems:**

- Permissions of viewing different pages are categorized as site roles. Site roles can only be applied to a particular site, and cannot be assigned to an organization.
- Organizations are required to simplify user management within the site.
- I prefer not to separate it into 2 different sites.

What is the best way to achieve the desired outcome? Also, do correct me if I made wrong assumptions about how roles work in Liferay. Thank you.

Comment: This is not really programming-related, as laid out in [help/on-topic]. You'll find better help (and the question will be on topic) within the Liferay community at https://liferay.dev/ask or the community's slack channel

Comment: Well - now I see that you seem to have done that already, so [please note this etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)